# How to convert letters to numbers in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to convert letters from user input into numbers in a MIPS assembly program. For example, A -> 1, B -> 2, C -> 3, and so on. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Subtract `'A'-1`?

Comment: Use a math.  Finding and programming a mathematical formula is language independent.

Comment: In ASCII, the uppercase alphabet is contiguous.  https://www.asciitable.com/